# How can I detect objects within canvas of gojs in codedui?

Tags: canvas, coded-ui-tests, gojs

Recently I have been assigned to do automated testing of an application which has GoJS canvas. In Application Under Testing (AUT) user can drag and drop different objects on canvas of GoJS.
My goal is to do automated testing of that functionality of AUT. But I am facing problem in detecting objects within canvas.
Is there any way to get the details of properties of objects dropped on canvas from within Codedui frame work of Microsoft? I have Visual studio 2015 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know about **BrowserWindow.ExecuteScript**.

I don't know what situation you have -- what your app does and what you need to test.  Basically, you'll want to execute JavaScript that starts with:

```
var diagramDiv = document.getElementById("myDiagramDiv");
var diagram = go.Diagram.fromDiv(diagramDiv);
```

and then does whatever it needs to use the [GoJS](http://gojs.net) [API](http://gojs.net/latest/api).  Some simple possibilities include:

```
return diagram.nodes.count;
```

or

```
return diagram.findPartAt(new go.Point(120, 76), true) !== null;
```

or

```
return diagram.model.findNodeDataForKey("abc").someProperty;
```

or arbitrarily more complex computations to look at the state of the diagram or of the diagram's model.  In fact, you could write all of your tests in JavaScript and return something summarizing the results.